Why are my blank columns in a DataFrame not being removed by dropna()
I have a dataframe that looks something like this:
date-time                   val 1   val 2   val 3
sample date-time 1          92      81      100
sample date-time 2          84      78      96
sample date-time 3          79              100
sample date-time 4          84      83  
sample date-time 5                  80      100
sample date-time 6          84      83      95

(note the missing values in multiple columns)
I'm trying to remove all rows that have atleast 1 missing value in columns val 1 or val 3 using dropna but it doesn't do anything.
Here's what I tried:
dftest = df.dropna(subset=['val 1', 'val 3'], how='all')
dftest

but this makes no changes in the dataframe. I suspect the values might not be being considered as empty or nans but I've no idea as to how or why that could happen. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

You should provide a [mre]. If that's the printed output of your dataframe, those empty spaces aren't nan. If they were, they would show up as NaN.

If that's the printed output of the dataframe, most likely those columns are dtype object containing integers and empty/whitespace strings, but it's not clear without the MRE.

@tdy The blanks appear so when converted to excel. On printing the dataframe they appear as NaNs, sorry for not including this point.

You should change to how='any'. See the doc

Still, please paste the output of print(dftest.to_dict() so we can be sure about the input data

remove how='all'

You have an extensive answer here. You need df.dropna(subset=['val 1', 'val 3'], how='any'). If you have empty strings: df.replace('', pd.NA).dropna(subset=['val 1', 'val 3'], how='any')

changing how = 'any' worked, thanks @mozway @PandaKim @Tranbi
